# Converting values in an array to multidimension array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have this method which generates a list with 81 int value inside it

```
int data[] = new int[10];
 List lst=new ArrayList();
 for(int j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
 for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
     lst.add(i);
 }
 }
 Collections.shuffle(lst);

 System.out.println(lst);
```

I want to convert it to  9*9 array. Can anyone help me with this. My output looks like this

```
[6, 5, 6, 5, 3, 9, 8, 1, 7, 7, 3, 4, 6, 6, 1, 5, 8, 4, 9, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 8, 5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 8, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 1, 8, 3, 5, 4, 1, 9, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1, 7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 2, 1, 4, 9, 7, 7, 3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 9, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: converting it to a 9*9 array.

Comment: Which part of that task, _specifically,_ are you unable to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do (Tell me if this isn't).

I rewrite the for loop with a two-dimensional array. In this way, lst becomes a 9*9 array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int data[] = new int[10];
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(9);
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length - 1; j++) {
        lst.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            lst.get(j).add(i);
        }
    }

    // shuffle can only process 1-dimension array
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length - 1; j++) {
        Collections.shuffle(lst.get(j));
    }

    // display the result in a 2-dimensional array format
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(lst.get(j).get(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

here is the output of the program:

```
8, 3, 7, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4, 0, 
4, 8, 6, 0, 7, 1, 5, 3, 2, 
6, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 0, 2, 5, 
6, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 7, 0, 5, 
1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5, 8, 0, 
1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 8, 7, 0, 6, 
1, 7, 3, 0, 5, 4, 6, 8, 2, 
0, 8, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 1, 5, 
8, 2, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7,
```

Comment: i want to make to as an 9*9 array [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

Comment: So you want the numbers in the array ordered ascendingly?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
int data[] = new int[10]; 
 List lst=new ArrayList();  
for(int j = 1; j < data.length; j++) { 
 List range=new ArrayList();  
for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
         range.add(i);  
} 
Collections.shuffle(range); 
lst.add(range);  }  
string result =lst.toString().replace(",", "");  
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: my output looks like this [6, 5, 6, 5, 3, 9, 8, 1, 7, 7, 3, 4, 6, 6, 1, 5, 8, 4, 9, 9, 7, 9, 3, 3, 8, 5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 8, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 1, 8, 3, 5, 4, 1, 9, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1, 7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 2, 1, 4, 9, 7, 7, 3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 9, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5] which has to be changed to an array format

Comment: give me a example of the result that you want

Comment: [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                                                                                               1 3 4 2 5 7 6 8 9.....]                                                                                                         orders can be random and no commas.

Comment: i have edit my answer, see if it solves your problem